# How to set the USB port name in raspberry pi 3?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi-desktop

I'm using 2 ports such as /dev/ttyUSB0 and /dev/ttyACM0, but when I remove one of this ports and put it again, the port's identification changes. How can I force a name to my fisical port in order to not have to change the name in my code?

Comment: **Raspberry Pi Desktop - a operating system for PC and Mac** has NOTHING to do with the Pi - what OS are you using?

Comment: @MATHEUS HENRIQUE NASCIMENTO DA, Ah, let me see. Does this tutorial help?  Howto: persistent device names on Raspberry Pi
https://rolfblijleven.blogspot.com/2015/02/howto-persistent-device-names-on.html

Comment: `udev` is the way to go (see tlfong's link).

Comment: I've done [this](https://g0kao.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/usb-port-assignment-on-a-raspberry-pi/) and it worked great. However, it might be better to use the {serial} as the identifier, especially if your going to use duplicate usb devices.